# How to make ALE to work with mixed Windows/Cygwin and tricore-gcc?

Tags: c, vim, vim-plugin, linter, vim-ale

EDITED: I am running on `Windows 10`, working with `gvim` but the overall project is built in `Cygwin`. The compiler that I am using is `tricore-gcc`. With lot of pain I managed to build a `compile_commands.json` file that apparently is working fine (if I use a linter that cannot parse `compile_commands.json` I immediately have an error on the first `#include` whereas if I use e.g. `clangtidy` such an error disappear).

Nevertheless, I tried to mess around with a `.c` file by removing some `;` or `}` to check if the linter is working, but nothing happens.

I tried to debug a bit by running the commands displayed in `ALEInfo` from both the `Powershell` and `Cygwin`, but I got the following error:

```
C:\> clang-tidy C:\Project1\Root\software\ComponentONE\src\fileA.c -p C:\Project1\Root
Skipping C:\Project1\Root\software\ComponentONE\src\fileA.c. Compile command not found.
```

I also tried to adjust the `compile_commands.json` by changing `/` with `\` (the same for the commands run from the `Powershell`), I tried to replace `tricore-gcc` with `gcc`, etc. but I always got the same error as above.

If I just run

```
C:\>clang-tidy.exe
clang-tidy.exe: Not enough positional command line arguments specified!
Must specify at least 1 positional arguments: See: C:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM\bin\clang-tidy.exe -help
```

which means that `clang-tidy` is recognized.

Finally, if I run the real compiler command:

`C:\> tricore-gcc.exe (various flags) C:\Project1\Root\software\ComponentONE\src\fileA.c`

from both `Powershell`  or `Cygwin` I don't get any error.

It follows my `ALEInfo`

```
 Current Filetype: c
Available Linters: ['cc', 'ccls', 'clangd', 'clangtidy', 'cppcheck', 'cquery', 'flawfinder']
   Linter Aliases:
'cc' -> ['gcc', 'clang']
  Enabled Linters: ['clangtidy']
  Ignored Linters: []
 Suggested Fixers: 
  'astyle' - Fix C/C++ with astyle.
  'clang-format' - Fix C/C++ and cuda files with clang-format.
  'clangtidy' - Fix C/C++ and ObjectiveC files with clang-tidy.
  'remove_trailing_lines' - Remove all blank lines at the end of a file.
  'trim_whitespace' - Remove all trailing whitespace characters at the end of every line.
  'uncrustify' - Fix C, C++, C#, ObjectiveC, ObjectiveC++, D, Java, Pawn, and VALA files with uncrustify.
 Linter Variables:

let g:ale_c_always_make = 0
let g:ale_c_build_dir = ''
let g:ale_c_build_dir_names = ['build', 'bin']
let g:ale_c_clangtidy_checks = []
let g:ale_c_clangtidy_executable = 'clang-tidy'
let g:ale_c_clangtidy_extra_options = ''
let g:ale_c_clangtidy_options = ''
let g:ale_c_parse_compile_commands = 1
let g:ale_c_parse_makefile = 0
 Global Variables:

let g:ale_cache_executable_check_failures = v:null
let g:ale_change_sign_column_color = 0
let g:ale_command_wrapper = ''
let g:ale_completion_delay = 100
let g:ale_completion_enabled = 0
let g:ale_completion_max_suggestions = 50
let g:ale_disable_lsp = 0
let g:ale_echo_cursor = 1
let g:ale_echo_msg_error_str = 'Error'
let g:ale_echo_msg_format = '%code: %%s'
let g:ale_echo_msg_info_str = 'Info'
let g:ale_echo_msg_warning_str = 'Warning'
let g:ale_enabled = 1
let g:ale_fix_on_save = 0
let g:ale_fixers = {'c': ['clangtidy'], '*': ['remove_trailing_lines', 'trim_whitespace']}
let g:ale_history_enabled = 1
let g:ale_history_log_output = 1
let g:ale_keep_list_window_open = 0
let g:ale_lint_delay = 200
let g:ale_lint_on_enter = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_filetype_changed = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_insert_leave = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_save = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_text_changed = 'normal'
let g:ale_linter_aliases = {}
let g:ale_linters = {'c': ['clangtidy']}
let g:ale_linters_explicit = 0
let g:ale_linters_ignore = {}
let g:ale_list_vertical = 0
let g:ale_list_window_size = 10
let g:ale_loclist_msg_format = '%code: %%s'
let g:ale_max_buffer_history_size = 20
let g:ale_max_signs = -1
let g:ale_maximum_file_size = v:null
let g:ale_open_list = 0
let g:ale_pattern_options = v:null
let g:ale_pattern_options_enabled = v:null
let g:ale_root = {}
let g:ale_set_balloons = 0
let g:ale_set_highlights = 1
let g:ale_set_loclist = 1
let g:ale_set_quickfix = 0
let g:ale_set_signs = 1
let g:ale_sign_column_always = 0
let g:ale_sign_error = '>>'
let g:ale_sign_info = '--'
let g:ale_sign_offset = 1000000
let g:ale_sign_style_error = '>>'
let g:ale_sign_style_warning = '--'
let g:ale_sign_warning = '--'
let g:ale_sign_highlight_linenrs = 0
let g:ale_statusline_format = v:null
let g:ale_type_map = {}
let g:ale_use_global_executables = v:null
let g:ale_virtualtext_cursor = 0
let g:ale_warn_about_trailing_blank_lines = 1
let g:ale_warn_about_trailing_whitespace = 1
  Command History:
(executable check - success) clang-tidy
(finished - exit code 0) 'cmd /s/c "clang-tidy C:\Project1\Root\software\ComponentONE\src\fileA.c -p C:\Project1\Root"'
<<<NO OUTPUT RETURNED>>>
```

and my _vimrc

```
let g:ale_linters = {
\ 'c': ['clangtidy'],
\}
let g:ale_fixers = ['clangtidy']
let g:ale_fixers={
\   'c': ['clangtidy'],
\   '*': ['remove_trailing_lines', 'trim_whitespace'],
\}
```

and one extract of my `compile_commands.json` file:

```
{
  "directory": ".",
  "command": "c:/Hightec/tricore/v4.6.6.1/bin/tricore-gcc.exe (number of flags) -c software/ComponentONE/src/fileA.c",
  "file": "software/ComponentONE/src/fileA.c"
},
```

If I run `pwd` from vim I have `C:\Project1\Root`

Comment: You should use the plugin's issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED!

I had to change the `compile_commands.json` file in this way:

```
{
  "directory": "C:/Project1/Root",
  "command": "c:/Hightec/tricore/v4.6.6.1/bin/tricore-gcc.exe (number of flags) -c software/ComponentONE/src/fileA.c",
  "file": "software/ComponentONE/src/fileA.c"
},
```

or in this way

```
{
  "directory": ".",
  "command": "c:/Hightec/tricore/v4.6.6.1/bin/tricore-gcc.exe (number of flags) -c software/ComponentONE/src/fileA.c",
  "file": "C:/Project1/Root/software/ComponentONE/src/fileA.c"
},
```

to make it to work.
Obviously now there are other issues such as

```
error: unknown argument: '-fstrict-volatile-bitfields' [clang-diagnostic-error]
```

but this because the option `-fstrict-volatile-bitfields` exists for `gcc` but for `clang`.
I would say problem solved.